# Chandra Vamsha -- Nahusha link to Budha

Tags: mahabharata, chandravansh

Mahabharata Adi Parva describes in detail the lunar dynasty. From Vaivaswata manu > Ila > Pururavas > Ayus to Nahusha.

> It was Pururavas who first brought from the region of the Gandharvas the
> three kinds of fire (for sacrificial purpose). And he brought thence, the
> Apsara Urvasi also. And the son of Ila begat upon Urvasi six sons who
> were called Ayus, Dhimat, Amavasu and Dhridhayus, and Vanayus, and
> Satayus.

and,

> And it is said that Ayus begat four sons named Nahusha

How does Ila's children/dynasty link to Chandra (moon) or his son Budha?

Comment: Ila was Pururava's mother..and Buddha was Pururava's father..

Comment: @yds thanks. Closing this. But I have posted a question/comment in original answer. Hope you can answer.